# Instagram Logout API

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, api, instagram

I'm using the Instagram API for my latest app and am having problems with logging out of Instagram within the App. Has anyone else had problems with this or know of a way to fix this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a simple workaround for this issue. It's not the most elegant, but still may be useful.

In the Instagram.m where authorizeWithSafary method is located, instead of opening the generated igAppUrl string in Safari, send a notification with this string to some webview which will handle instagram login page.

Then watch for a current request in shouldStartLoadWithRequest. The request with actual redirect URI usually ends with error, so when you catch this request (don't forget to check for your app's redirect URI though), hide your webview.

At the same time you'll receive this URI, your application will be already handling the rest of authorization logic, as if you were authorising with Safari. However, if your app doesn't receive this URI, you can also manually grab that from request and manually call delegate's handleOpenURL method.

With such approach, the logout logic will work as expected, since we're clearing our app's instagram-related cached data. However, I don't think this is a good practice, since we're redirecting to our app from our app in this case.

Maybe transferring handleOpenURL method's logic to some other notification-based methods would be better, but I didn't have much time to try that.

**This Awesome answer was provided by this man on git hub **
[Apolotary answer](https://github.com/crino/instagram-ios-sdk/issues/4)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a pretty simple solution. As [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/) maintains session in Safari, So just send a request to http://instagram.com/accounts/logout/ on Logout button tap event in your app and you are done.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score -1):

Im making android app using html5, I did the following:
Redirect the user to a html5 page containing following code:

```
            <div id = "loading" style="text-align: center; display:block; margin-top: 150px;">
                    <img alt="" src="/css/themes/images/ajax-loader.gif" width="46px" height="46px">
                    <br><font style="text-align: center;">Logging Out...</font>
            </div>

        </div>
```